# Switching to Cloudflare DNS triggers this error "Unsupported X-Forwarded-Proto: https, https for URL" with mod_pagespeed 1.11.33.5-0 @26313

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have multiple domains on the same server, all setup with Cloudflare DNS and no problems, but for one domain I get this error whenever I try switching DNS to Cloudflare :

`[Sat Dec 05 11:41:22.471013 2020] [pagespeed:warn] [pid 26313:tid 140310743021312] [mod_pagespeed 1.11.33.5-0 @26313] [1205/114122:WARNING:instaweb_context.cc(402)] Unsupported X-Forwarded-Proto: https, https for URL http://mydomain/page.php? protocol not changed` .

- I thought it was maybe CF forced HTTPS rewrite, but it does the same when I disable it.
- I looked also in the .htaccess but found nothing related to HTTPS rewrite. I even deleted the .htaccess to test but it did not stop the warnings.
- I tried changing all the settings on CF but nothing made a difference.
- I really think its an issue on my server side, but its weird that none of the other domains suffer the same issue.
- I don't have much control on the apache config of my host

Comment: Please be a bit more complete about your setup. Are you using a load balancer or proxy? Are you browsing to ```http://yourdomain``` or ```https://yourdomain```? Are you sure changing DNS servers had anything to do with the issue or could it be a coincidence it happened at the same time? Will the option ```ModPagespeedRespectXForwardedProto off``` suppress the error?

Comment: 1. using only https://
2. Its Cloudflare DNS change for sure, its not the first time I try to make that change and its always the same results. I tried disabling ALL the features of CF but made no difference
3. I tried to to add : `<IfModule pagespeed_module>
    ModPagespeed off
</IfModule>`
To my .htaccess but it made no difference either.

Comment: Can you confirm the value of the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header? (This is set by Cloudflare and perhaps any other intermediary proxy _as well_ - which may be the problem here). The "warning" would suggest it is set to `https, https` and [mod_pagespeed appears to be coded to throw a warning](https://github.com/apache/incubator-pagespeed-ngx/blob/master/src/ngx_pagespeed.cc) if it's not exactly `http` or `https`. The problem here is that `https, https` isn't necessarily wrong (since there is no _official_ standard).

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Unsupported X-Forwarded-Proto: https, https
> ```

This would imply you have a proxy (or "load balancer") in addition to Cloudflare. Both will set an `X-Forwarded-Proto` header and one or other is *merging* them (arguably incorrectly, according to the "HTTP standard" at least, although `X-Forwarded-Proto` is only a defacto standard so there are no official rules governing how multiple headers should be merged, so `https, https` isn't necessarily wrong.)

[mod_pagespeed](https://github.com/apache/incubator-pagespeed-ngx/blob/master/src/ngx_pagespeed.cc#L1616) appears to be hardcoded to issue this warning if this header (when set) is not exactly `http` or `https`:

> ```
>   if (!STR_CASE_EQ_LITERAL(*x_forwarded_proto_header, "http") &&
>       !STR_CASE_EQ_LITERAL(*x_forwarded_proto_header, "https")) {
>     LOG(WARNING) << "Unsupported X-Forwarded-Proto: " << x_forwarded_proto
>                  << " for URL " << url << " protocol not changed.";
>     return false;
>   }
> ```

Try setting the following in your `.htaccess` (or server config) to change this to simply `https`:

```
RequestHeader edit X-Forwarded-Proto "^https,\s?https$" "https" early
```

If this doesn't work, try removing the `early` argument.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. To my knowledge, I have not set a Load balancer on CF or on my host. Its a cloud hosting so it could be that the hosting has its own setup that I have no control over. For now I had to disable CF, it was putting too much trouble on my service.
The other thing which makes me tick is that I have a lot of other domains on this cloud, all with Cloudflare and none of them has this issue. They all share the same config on the host too (there is very little one can change so its easy to track)

Comment: Did you try the `RequestHeader` directive as posted in my answer? Many cloud/shared hosting solutions do use proxy servers, even if it's just for caching. You should examine the HTTP request headers reaching your application server _and_ the response headers your application is sending back - this could give you a clue as to what's going on.

Comment: I have not.. my "definitive" solution is to move to AWS with Cloudfront, it seems to work fine there. Cannot afford to wait on "testing" things with this domain, but if it comes up again on another one, I will test. Thanks for your suggestions.